# Getting a value using WordPress custom fields

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to output demo and download links for posts using custom fields if its required.

Here is the sample code

`<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "demo", true) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <div class="demo" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "demo", true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>`

Help me, whats making wrong with this code

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket in your if statement...
Try this instead:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "demo", true)) : ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
        <img class="demo" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "demo", true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Also, I believe your div should be an img tag... you might want to correct that as well. (edited above as well)